# Angular Form array value changes does not fire first time

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a formArray within my form. When the control of the form array is changed I am putting a console in 'year1 changed'. The problem this console is not fired the first time but fired every time after that. Also the console 'comes here' is fired every time.

Any idea why 'year1 changed' is not fired the first time?

```
    this.costTable().valueChanges
        .pipe(
            filter(filter => this.form.dirty),
            tap(_=> console.log('comes here')),
            switchMap( costs => {
                const otherCost$: Observable<number>[] = this.costTable().controls.map( ( c, i ) => {
                    return c.get('year1').valueChanges
                        .pipe(
                            tap( row => {
                                // if other costs changed
                                console.log('year1 changed')

                            } )
                        )
                } )
                return merge(...otherCost$);
            })
        ).subscribe();
```

Comment: It doesn’t emit the initial value, only when it “changes”.  If you want to emit the initial value, you could use `startWith(form.value)`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by removing the filter on the main form and adding in on form array

```
this.costTable().valueChanges
    .pipe(
        tap(_=> console.log('comes here')),
        switchMap( costs => {
            const otherCost$: Observable<number>[] = this.costTable().controls.map( ( c, i ) => {
                return c.get('year1').valueChanges
                    .pipe(
                        filter(filter => c.dirty),
                        tap( row => {
                            // if other costs changed
                            console.log('year1 changed')

                        } )
                    )
            } )
            return merge(...otherCost$);
        })
    ).subscribe();
```